# Simple Drone Propeller Simulation

Tags: matlab, simulink

I designed a propeller with CatiaV5 and imported it into simulink 3D animation.How do I induce a rotation motion about its central axis to the propeller?I tried using the approach used in the 3D animation file 'vrmemb1' provided by matlab,it makes the proppeller rotate but not on its center axis.

Comment: Please post the code in question so that we can assist you.

Comment: I've not used any code so far,there is only two simulink blocks,one that appears when you write 'vrmemb1' in Matlab command window and a 3D animation block.My idea is to just induce a rotational motion to the propeller about its center axis